# oracle sum count over a range of dates

Tags: sql, oracle, select, count

I have a Oracle table that has a record for every day for the last two years. The date table has only one column that stores a date value. 
I have a second table that records email opens. The columns are subscriber_id,
time_opened, message id.

I'd like to produce a report that includes every date from the date table and
also has a count of unique subscriber_ids that have a record in the opens table with the past 180 days. 
I was hoping to do this without using a loop but if that is the only option I am open to suggestions.

Comment: You have a better chance to get some answers if you provide some code, i.e. ddl for your tables and inserts with sample data. You can then also show your expected results.

Answer (score 1):

You could join both tables and apply the aggregate `count` function:

```
SELECT    d.date_column, COALESCE(COUNT(DISTINCT subscriber_id), 0)
FROM      dates d
LEFT JOIN subscribsers s ON d.date_column = TRUNC(s.time_opened) 
WHERE     d.date_column >= SYSDATE - 180
GROUP BY  d.date_column
```

Comment: This will query will only return the last six month of date values from the dates table. The sysdate - 180 needs to be applied to the subscribers table.

Comment: The join is on the date, so it's pretty equivalent.

Comment: Brian, if you want to include all dates whether there was a subscription or not then the sysdate - 180 needs to be applied to the dates table.

Comment: Mureinik, your query is incorrect. The WHERE clause effectively turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN. You should move the WHERE clause to the LEFT JOIN (in this case replace WHERE by AND).